Read json file in Reactjs in a similar way to what im doing in Angular?
I have a json file in the assets folder of my Angular project. I use it to store generic tooltips and labels, so i dont have to hard code them in my HTML code. First i'll show how i read this json file inside my app.
An example of what i have inside of it:
"Tooltips": {
    "Editar": "Editar",
    "Eliminar": "Eliminar",
    "Ver": "Ver",
    "Footer": {
      "Facebook": "Seguinos en Facebook",
      "Twitter": "Seguinos en X",
      "Instagram": "Seguinos en Instagram",
      "Linkedin": "Seguinos en Linkedin",
      "YouTube": "Seguinos en YouTube"
    }
  }

I have a service that's dedicated to read this json file:
@Injectable()
export class ConfigService {
  private _tooltips: ITooltips
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  readData() {
    const promise = this.http
      .get('assets/config.json', { responseType: 'text' }).toPromise();

    promise.then(data => {
      const config = parseJson(data)
      this._tooltips = config['Tooltips']
    
    })

    return promise
  }

 public get tooltips(): ITooltips {
    return this._tooltips
  }

interface ITooltips {
  Editar: string,
  Ver: string,
  Eliminar: string,

  Footer: {
    Facebook: string,
    Twitter: string,
    Instagram: string,
    Linkedin: string,
    YouTube: string
  }
}

"parseJson" refers to this method, which uses the strip-json-comments library:
export function parseJson(jsonText: string): any {
  const stripedJson = stripJsonComments(jsonText)
  const json = JSON.parse(stripedJson)

  return json
}

code inside the app.module.ts:
export function initializeApp(config: ConfigService) {
  return () => config.readData()
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  ],
  imports: [
  ],

  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
  providers: [
    ConfigService,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initializeApp,
      deps: [ConfigService],
      multi: true,
    }

  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

All of this makes it so i can inject the ConfigService service inside any of my components and read the config.json file, which is very convenient in my opinion.
Now, im about to start a new Reactjs project in my job. I have little to no experience in Reactjs, we're gonna have a ton of training first, but i was thinking about this specific part of my Angular app.
I would like to "translate" this code from Angular to Reactjs. I wanna be able to map a json file to one or multiple Interfaces in something similar to an Angular service, so i can inject it an read the file from anywhere in my Reactjs app.
How can i do this? What libraries do you recommend?

why not using context file instead of json this is a better approach:
first create a file named ToolTips.js
const Tooltips = {
    Editar: "Editar",
    Eliminar: "Eliminar",
    Ver: "Ver",
    Footer: {
        Facebook: "Seguinos en Facebook",
        Twitter: "Seguinos en X",
        Instagram: "Seguinos en Instagram",
        Linkedin: "Seguinos en Linkedin",
        YouTube: "Seguinos en YouTube"
    }
}

export { Tooltips }

then create Tooltips Context file like this:
import React, { createContext, useContext } from 'react';
import { ToolTips } from '../Constants/ToolTips';

const ToolTipsContext = createContext();

export const ToolTipsProvider = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <ToolTipsContext.Provider value={{ ToolTips }}>
      {children}
    </ToolTipsContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useToolTips = () => useContext(ToolTipsContext);

then use context in app like this:
import React from 'react';
import { ToolTipsProvider } from './context/ToolTipsContext';
import TooltipComponent from './components/TooltipComponent';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <ToolTipsProvider>
      <div>
        <h1>My App</h1>
        <AnyComponent/>
      </div>
    </ToolTipsProvider>
  );
};

export default App;

then you can use it in your component like this:
import React from 'react';
import { useToolTips } from '../context/ToolTipsContext';

const AnyComponent= () => {
  const { Tooltips } = useToolTips();

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Tooltips Example</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>{Tooltips.Editar}</li>
        <li>{Tooltips.Eliminar}</li>
        <li>{Tooltips.Ver}</li>
        <h3>Footer</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>{Tooltips.Footer.Facebook}</li>
          <li>{Tooltips.Footer.Twitter}</li>
          <li>{Tooltips.Footer.Instagram}</li>
          <li>{Tooltips.Footer.Linkedin}</li>
          <li>{Tooltips.Footer.YouTube}</li>
        </ul>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AnyComponent;

in this way you can use the tooltips in any component inside of the app even if there is a 1000 page the tooltips can be used in all of them without repeating code.

did it help you?
